# как решить задачу в byte of python swaroop'a

Tags: python

при изучении python'а по книге byte of python столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Наиболее важным усовершенствованием было бы прекращение использования
os.system для создания архивов, а применение вместо него встроенных модулей
zipfile или tarfile. Они являются частью стандартной библиотеки, поэтому всегда доступны для использования без зависимости от внешней программы zip на компьютере.
В приведённых примерах мы использовали способ с os.system для создания резервных
копий исключительно в педагогических целях, чтобы пример был достаточно прост для
понимания любым читателем, но достаточно реален для того, чтобы делать что-то полезное.
Попробуйте написать пятую версию с использованием модуля zipfile вместо вызова
os.system

конкретно втупил на этой задаче, искал документацию к модулю `zipfile`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html, однако мало что понял. заранее большое спасибо!

вот мой код:

```
import os, time as t, sys, zipfile

# Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
list = []
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    new = f'\"{i}\"' #придаем двойные кавычки, если в файле есть пробелы
    list.append(new)
print(list)
source = ['"C:\\my documents"']
source.extend(list)

print(source)

target_dir = 'D:\\backup'

today = os.path.join(target_dir, t.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today) # создание каталога, если он отсутствует
    print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

now = t.strftime('%H%M%S.zip')

comment = input('Введите имя zip архива --> ')

if len(comment) == 0: # Если пользователь ничего не ввел, то имя zip архива - now
    target = os.path.join(today, now)
else:
    target = os.path.join(today, comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip')

# Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив:

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: Вы пишете `new = f'\"{i}\"' #придаем двойные кавычки, если в файле есть пробелы` Но если у Вас будут пробелы в имени файла в argv то каждая часть такого имени будет отдельным аргументом, а если название как аргумент будет уже в кавычках то подставление кавычек здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ показывает как можно реализовать решение Вашей задачи

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

target_dir = Path(r'C:\backup').joinpath(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
source = Path(r'C:\documents')

target_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

archive = ZipFile(target_dir.joinpath('backup.zip'), 'w')

for item in source.rglob('*'):
    archive.write(item.absolute())

archive.close()
```